# Running bash script after WGET ignores read user input

Tags: linux, bash, shell, debian, wget

I'm trying to create a bash script that can be easily downloaded and run from terminal. Inside the bash script there are a couple of user inputs.

Running:

```
sudo wget -O - https://script.com/script.sh | bash
```

This will download the script and run it with bash but will ignore the user input in script.sh:

```
echo "Please enter a username:"
read -p 'Username: ' uservar
echo "Please enter a strong password:"
read -sp 'Password: ' passvar
echo
echo "
user=$uservar
password=$passvar
" >> ~/.data/cred.conf
echo "Succesfully installed."
```

Running:

```
sudo wget -O - https://script.com/script.sh && bash ./script.sh
```

Works fine and prompts for user input. Is there any way to make user input work with a pipe (`| bash`) ?

Comment: maybe using `| bash <(cat) </dev/tty`

Comment: See [Piping a script with “read” to bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/180386/153195)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from comment

```
| bash <(cat) </dev/tty
```

why and how it works

- `<(cat)` construct allows

  - to create a process which reads from inherited input, at this point, it's the pipe output
  - to redirect output to a file descriptor used as a file and process expansion is changed to a string used as a file name
- `</dev/tty` redirects pseudo terminal device `/dev/tty` to input of bash process